# Get all values from LDAP entries (with same names) and store them in Lotus Notes with Java

Tags: java, jndi, lotus-notes

I am retrieving account information from an LDAP/AD via JNDI from an agent in Lotus Notes. That works just fine. My problem are the atrributes/values with equal names e.g. there are ObjectClass and ObjectType which are availible multiple times in the entry. I want to store the values as a multitext entry in LotusNotes with the following code

```
for (NamingEnumeration ae = atts.getAll(); ae.hasMore();) {
    Attribute attr = (Attribute) ae.next();

    Item mItem = newDoc.getFirstItem(fPre + "_" + attr.getID());
    if(mItem == null){
        newDoc.replaceItemValue(fPre + "_" + attr.getID(), attr.get());
    }else{
        mItem.appendToTextList("" + attr.get());
    }
}
```

But I only get always one value. So do I accessing the entry in the LDAP/AD the wrong way or is the storing in Notes wrong (is not possible to access the Item without saving, like it is possible with LotusScript)?

Thanks
Armin

Comment: Your code looks correct.  Assuming that attr.get() returns the same value multiple times, you should be getting a non-null result from getFirstItem and be going into the else clause the 2nd (3rd, 4th...) etc. time.  So my question is: are you seeing that in the debugger?  Do you actually see it execute the appendToTextList() method?

Comment: Assuming that attr.get() returns a String, does mItem.Type return "TEXT" and is defined as a multivalue field?

Comment: I didn't get the java debugging running in Notes. But I put the code outside in Netbeans and tried it there to see what I get. And it looks like I missanderstand something in LDAP. If I look ontu the LDAP via my Client I see multiple Objectclass entries (each with a single value) but if I run the code I always geht only one (I print each value onto the console). So I think it's not really a Notes issue.